# add attachment picture into html email body in office 16 / O365

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have been using this code in office 2013:

```
With OutMail
            .Attachments.Add fName
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><B>" & ChartName &   :</B><br>" _ & "<img src='" & fName(i) & "' width='800'  height='400'><br>" _

            .Display
        End With
```

where fName is full path to png file and Chartname is just a headline for the graph.

This has always worked fine but now in office 2016 / O365 this code pastes an empty html table into the outloop email and no graph or picture is visible. 
Any pointers how to fix this would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

There are errors on your .HTMLBody line.  Try this instead:

```
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><B>" & ChartName & ":</B><br>" & "<img src='" & 
fName(i) & "' width='800'  height='400'><br>"
```

I added a quote and removed unneeded `_`.

Comment: sorry but this doesnt work in the new office either.

Comment: I corrected the syntax, but there could be logic errors, too.  One thing I notice, however, is `fName(i)`.  If fName is not an array remove `(i)`.

Comment: tks, its an array. this code works but not in the new excel unfortunately. So this doesnt fix the problem.

Comment: If that's the case, then doesn't `.Attachments.Add fName` need to be `.Attachments.Add fName(i)`?

Comment: Does it help if you replace `"<img src='"` with `"<img src='cid:"` ?

Comment: thank you yor your help, but there is nothing fundamentally wrong with my code, it works fine in 2013 just not in 2016

Answer (score 0):

Create an attachment and set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"`) using `Attachment.PropertyAccessor`.

Your HTML body (`MailItem.HTMLBody` property) would then need to reference that image attachment through the cid:

```
img src="cid:xyz"
```

where xyz is the value of the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property.

Look at an existing message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click IMessage button).

```
attachment = mailitem.Attachments.Add("c:\temp\MyPicture.jpg")
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyId1")
mailitem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>Test image <img src=""cid:MyId1""></body></html>"
```