# How to insert/embed an image file(.png) in emails while sending in c++/COM?

Tags: c++, email, outlook

When user is sending email, I need to insert/embed image in email. I am getting Outlook::Applciation's Send Event and getting the body of the email. I need to append/embed an image to the end of the email.

I am building a html as below and appending it to the body of an email.

```html
<html> <body>
L"<a href=\"www.X.org\"> <img height =\"30\" src = \"http://example.org\img\myimg.png \"></a>")</body></html>
```

This is working fine. But, I don't want to  get the image from URL. I need to load it from resource file and insert it in the email. Is this possible? What if my resource dll is not available in receiver's  machine? Will it still load the image?

I tried this as below -

```html
CComPtr<Outlook::Attachments> pNewas;
CComPtr<Outlook::Attachment> pNewa;
p->get_Attachments(&pNewas);
VARIANT atc;
VARIANT pos;
VARIANT type;
VARIANT Displ;
::VariantInit(&pos);
::VariantInit(&type);
Displ.vt = VT_BSTR;
Displ.bstrVal = L"images.png";
atc.vt = VT_BSTR;
atc.bstrVal = L"C:\\images.png" ; // This should be from resource file
pNewas->Add(atc, pos,type, Displ,&pNewa);



<html> <body>

L"<a href=\"www.X.org\"> <img height =\"30\" src = \'cid:images.png'></a>")

</body></html>
```

This is adding image while sending the email but receiver email don't see it in inbox. Also, when email is sent to gmail it shows as an attachment.

Is it possible to load the image from resource ? Or, there's no option other than loading from URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property.
See [add attachment picture into html email body in office 16 / O365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352499/add-attachment-picture-into-html-email-body-in-office-16-o365)